# Redshift Unload command with CSV extension

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'm using the following Unload command -

```
unload ('select * from '')to  's3://**summary.csv**'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id='';aws_secret_access_key=''' parallel off allowoverwrite CSV HEADER;
```

The file created in S3 is `summary.csv000`

If I change and remove the file extension from the command like below

```
unload ('select * from '')to  's3://**summary**'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id='';aws_secret_access_key=''' parallel off allowoverwrite CSV HEADER;
```

The file create in S3 is `summary000`

Is there a way to get **summary.csv**, so I don't have to change the file extension before importing it into excel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually a lot of folks asked the similar question, right now **it's not possible** to have an extension for the files. (but `parquet` files can have)

The reason behind this is, RedShift by default export it in parallel which is a good thing. Each slice will export its data. Also from the docs,

> **PARALLEL**
>
> By default, UNLOAD writes data in parallel to multiple files,
> according to the number of slices in the cluster. The default option
> is ON or TRUE. If PARALLEL is OFF or FALSE, UNLOAD writes to one or
> more data files serially, sorted absolutely according to the ORDER BY
> clause, if one is used. The maximum size for a data file is 6.2 GB.
> So, for example, if you unload 13.4 GB of data, UNLOAD creates the
> following three files.

So it has to create new files after **6GB** that's why they are adding numbers as a suffix.

### How do we solve this?

No native options from RedShift, but we can do some workaround with lambda.

1. Create a new S3 bucket and a folder inside it specifically for this process.(eg: `s3://unloadbucket/redshift-files/`)
2. Your unload files should go to this folder.
3. Lambda function should be triggered based on S3 put object event.
4. Then the lambda function,

   1. Download the file(if it is large use EFS)
   2. Rename it with `.csv`
   3. Upload to the same bucket(or different bucket) into a different path (eg: `s3://unloadbucket/csvfiles/`)

Or even more simple if you use shell/powershell script to do the following process

1. Download the file
2. Rename it with `.csv`

Comment: Still not working in simpliest way?

Comment: unfortunately, still its not possible with unload command @bigdataadd

Comment: this answer is no more correct see the answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/75617611/6227500

Answer (score 5):

Its a bit late but they recently added EXTENSION parameter that solves this problem:

```
1.0.45698 – Released on January 20, 2023
Release notes for this version:
- Adds a file extension parameter to the UNLOAD command, so file extensions are automatically added to filenames.
```

Comment: Great news! Link -
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html#:~:text=Amazon%20Redshift%20database.-,EXTENSION

Answer (score 0):

As per AWS Documentation around [UNLOAD](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) command, it's possible to save data as CSV.

In your case, this is what your code would look like:

```
unload ('select * from '')
to  's3://summary/'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id='';aws_secret_access_key=''' 
CSV <<<
parallel off 
allowoverwrite 
CSV HEADER;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to command EXTENSION 'csv'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
unload ('select * from '')to  's3://**summary.csv**'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id='';aws_secret_access_key=''' 
DELIMITER ','
HEADER
EXTENSION 'csv'
ALLOWOVERWRITE
PARALLEL OFF;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).